# dd: invalid argument 'ucase' to 'conv'

Tags: linux, unix, dd

Why 'ucase' value is not working for attribute 'conv' in unix ?

## Error info

➤ dd if=mergefile of=dddemo conv=ucase
dd: invalid argument 'ucase' to 'conv'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a version of `dd(1)` that doesn't understand the `ucase` conversion specifier, such as the one included with BusyBox.

Comment: just now seen that nothing is working in my sidedd: invalid argument 'ebcdic' to 'conv'

Comment: dd version
BusyBox v1.19.2 (2012-06-12 22:17:17    ) multi-call binary.

Comment: Well there you go then.

Comment: Either use a version of `dd(1)` that understands the argument or use something else to do what you want.

Comment: Find one from somewhere else, e.g. GNU Coreutils, and put it somewhere you can use it.

Comment: I arrived here from googling my dd error, and this answer clarified the problem quickly, thanks. One can see a list of valid args for busybox `dd` using `dd --help`. What confused *me* was the POSIX `man dd` page on Alpine Linux, which has no mention of the busyboxisms.